# Gradle 6.1 isn't finding the com.moowork.gulp plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Upgrading from Gradle 4.0 to 6.1, the com.moowork.glup plugin seems to have vanished.  Yet, the https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.gulp page show that the plugin does exist.  The sample code works with the com.moowork.gulp line commented out.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id "com.moowork.gulp" version "1.3.0"
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "8.0.3"
}

task testAgain {
    println 'Configuration stage'

    doLast {
        println 'Execution stage'
    }
}
```

Once the offending line is uncommented, the Gradle example fails.

```
$ ./gradlew -q  testAgain

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'example'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  > Could not find com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.3.0.
    Searched in the following locations:
    - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-node-plugin/1.3.0/gradle-node-plugin-1.3.0.pom
    If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
    Required by:
     project : > com.moowork.gulp:com.moowork.gulp.gradle.plugin:1.3.0
[...]

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

What am I missing?